# Using Laravel 5, how can I find out if a Mailgun email was sent successfully?

Tags: php, api, laravel-5, mailgun

I'm using the native Mailgun driver in Laravel 5 to send an email

```
\Mail::send('emails.notification', $data, function($message) use ($data)
{
  $message->to('name@gmail.com', 'Joe Bob')->subject("Headline here");
});
```

That works well and the emails are being received, but I would like to know how I can get a response from Mailgun letting me know that the email was sent.

How can I go about getting that information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution and it's actually quite simple.

**With Laravel (Using the [Bogardo Mailgun Package](https://github.com/Bogardo/Mailgun)):**

```
$to_name = "Jim Bob";
$to_email = "jimbob@gmail.com";
$subject = "Howdy everyone!";

// Send the email and capture the response from the Mailgun server
$response = Mailgun::send('emails.transactional', array('body' => $body), function($message) use($to_email, $to_name, $subject)
{
  $message->to($to_email, $to_name)->subject($subject);
});

// HTTP Response Code 200 means everything worked as expected
if ($response->http_response_code === 200) {
  echo "Woohoo! The message sent!";
}
```

**In plain ol' PHP (Using the official [Mailgun PHP SDK](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php)):**

```
// Config Information
$mailgun = new Mailgun("key-v876876dfsv876csd8768d876cfsd4");
$domain = "mg.mydomain.com";

// Prepare the necessary information to send the email
$send_data = array(
  'from' => $from_name . ' <' . $from_email . '>',
  'to' => $to_name . ' <' . $to_email . '>',
  'subject' => $subject,
  'html' => $html
);

// Send the email and capture the response from the Mailgun server
$response = $mailgun->sendMessage($domain, $send_data);

// HTTP Response Code 200 means everything worked as expected
if ($response->http_response_code === 200) {
  echo "Woohoo! The message sent!";
}
```

Check out a list of all Mailgun HTTP Response Codes: (https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-intro.html?highlight=401#errors)

Answer (score 2):

To know the status of the email you can use Mailgun webhooks. From the Mailgun admin area you can specify a webhook url that Mailgun will post to after they have processed your email.

Ensure that whatever url you use as a webhook exists in your application and has a route and method in whichever controller you are using. Once your application receives the posted data you can parse the data sent and determine the status of the email. You can then update your database or whatever you need to do.

To identify which email you will need to add some custom headers in the email so you can identify it later on.

see this answer for more details on how to do that: [Using Laravel's Mailgun driver, how do you (gracefully) send custom data and tags with your email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35848266/using-laravels-mailgun-driver-how-do-you-gracefully-send-custom-data-and-tag)

The webhook url needs to be live for it to work, so if you are testing locally with laravell homestead you can take a look at ngrok, which allows you to tunnel your local environment to a url which will work for testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but fortunately it's not all that difficult. Webhooks are great for other more advanced things but not necessary just to get a success response from Mailgun. Please refer to my answer I posted.

Comment: Does the 200 response not indicate that Mailgun has received your request successfully, Mailgun then go on to process the email giving a status of delivered, failed, bounced etc to each mail. I'm not 100% sure that it is successful using your method. Perhaps you could try sending it an email address that does not exist and if it gives a 200 response check mailgun logs which would showed failed sending.